# Function returns two values and both of them are returned

Tags: function, webpack, return, manifest

Inside my webpack.config I use webpack-assets-manifest plugin to generate manifest json file. I need to change the key name inside json object so I customize property following instructions in the docs and this works perfect. What I wonder about is how is this working? Inside my manifest.json file localBundle and localBundle.map are generated. Isn't function supposed to end after it hits first return? How come both if statements return something?

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
...
  new WebpackAssetsManifest({
      customize: (key, value) => {
        if (value.toLowerCase().endsWith('.local.css')) {
          return {
            key: 'localBundle',
            value: value
          }
        }
        if (value.toLowerCase().endsWith('.local.css.map')) {
          return {
            key: 'localBundle.map',
            value: value
          }
        }
      }
    }),
...
}
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  ...
  "localBundle": "stylesLocal.b035cc665aee76e41676ad101e93fd67.local.css",
  "localBundle.map": "stylesLocal.b035cc665aee76e41676ad101e93fd67.local.css.map",

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `customize` callback runs multiple times which is why your conditional return values are used in `manifest.json`.

If you're curious, [here is where `customize` is called](https://github.com/webdeveric/webpack-assets-manifest/blob/58a66beef4d863248fbe964ea696f938e0c5d5ec/src/WebpackAssetsManifest.js#L147).